# How to check if the decryption is correct?

Tags: encryption, decryption

I'm working on chat room that encrypt messages for more than one users and each user might have different encryption and key/password. The user's key won't work with all the message, therefore; return errors.

```
var message ="secret message";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, "Secret Passphrase");
try {
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase123").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    if (decrypted.length > 0) {
        alert(decrypted);
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
} catch(e) {
    alert("false");
}
```

I'm currently catching the error, but sometimes the decryption returns with jumbled up letters and symbols. The current way I'm doing this is not efficient. Is there a better way?

I ask this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663373/how-to-check-if-the-encryption-is-correct) earilier on stackoverflow, but they suggested that I might have bette luck here.

Comment: Here, this is currently a few posts under yours :)
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119887/how-to-know-if-a-file-is-decrypted-or-not

Check out the top comment on the question.

Comment: thanks, it sounds a little complicated but I think I kinda get it. (:

Comment: You might want to use an authenticated encryption scheme. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an authenticated mode like GCM. Not only will this tell you whether or not the correct key was used to decrypt, but it prevents message-tampering attacks, the worst of which can allow attackers to completely decrypt encrypted messages.

Comment: what is GCM? and how does it work?

Comment: [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) is an [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) mode. It should be provided out of the box by any reputable encryption library. In short, it aborts decryption early if the key, IV, and/or additional authenticated data are not the same values as were used to originally encrypt the payload.

Comment: okay, ill do that. this was sugessted on the other pages as well. I'll try to code it in with the decryption function in my JS.